# Login script with output of systeminfo

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a Windows batch login script that collects each user's system info and username/computername and outputs it to one log file (rather than a separate file created for each user). So I need something like `echo %username%-%computername% >> file.txt` and `systeminfo|find /i "original" >> file.txt`, which I managed to do with something like this:

```
systeminfo|find /i "original" >> \\share\sysinfo.log
echo %username%-%computername% >>\\share\user.log
type \\share\user.log > \\share\Results\systeminfo.log 
type \\share\sysinfo.log >> \\share\Results\systeminfo.log
```

Every time someone logs on, it output to one file, but the username and systeminfo are separated. I need them to output into separate columns, for example:

```
Username-ComputerName    Original Install Date
Jo-PC1                   17/16/2016, 09:14:34
Dan-PC2                  17/03/2015, 11:00:05
```

Answer (score 0):

Please mind that Stack Overflow is not a write-code-for-me-services. Anyways, I shamefully stole the script`(and edited)` by MC ND in my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697947/batch-file-dirs-result-seperated)

---

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
rem Prepare padding for two column
set "Width=30"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "padding= "
for /l %%a in (1 1 %Width%) do set "padding=!padding! "
endlocal & set "padding=%padding%"

rem return "Username-ComputerName    Original Install Date"
echo Username-ComputerName          Original Install Date>File.ext  

rem Prepate two files to store username-computerName and install date lists
for %%d in ("%temp%\username-computerName.%random%%random%%random%.tmp") do (
for %%f in ("%temp%\installName.%random%%random%%random%.tmp") do (

    rem Retrieve the list of username-computerName and install date into the temp files
    type user.log > "%%~fd" 2>nul 
    type date.log > "%%~ff" 2>nul 

    rem Assign each temporary file to a separate stream 
    rem and call the code to process them 
    9<"%%~fd" 8<"%%~ff" call :dumpPairs

    rem Clean up temporary files
) & del /q "%%~ff"
) & del /q "%%~fd"

rem All done, leave
cls
type File.ext
pause
goto :eof


rem Read stream 9 to retrieve username-computerName - Clean var on failure
rem Read stream 8 to retrieve install date - Clean var on failure
rem If both variables are uninitialized, there is nothing more to do
rem Concatenate both information and padding 
rem Echo the padded results
rem Repeat the process

:dumpPairs
<&9 set /p "username-computerName=" || set "username-computerName="
<&8 set /p "installName="      || set "installName="
if not defined username-computerName if not defined installName goto :eof

set "line=%username-computerName%%padding%"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo(!line:~0,%Width%! !installName!>>File.ext
endlocal

goto :dumpPairs
```

The explanation is already is inside the script, so I won't explain much.

- Simply get the result into 2 files
- Echo them together

The output part is

```
rem All done, leave
cls
type File.ext
pause
goto :eof
```

so you may need some adjustments.